# Socket.io v3 client from within chrome extension Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: express, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I am seeing this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined` in my chrome extension when I update the socket.io library from `v2.3.0` to `v3.1.0`

If I leave the old socket.io client, it seems unable to work with socket.io server `3.1.0` (I see this message on the request from browser developer tools network tab: `{"code":5,"message":"Unsupported protocol version"}` with an http `400 bad request` )

Is there an issue with socket.io v3.x and chrome extension?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

v3 change way for setup:
https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/index.html

Сrucial point it's explicitly, set cors policy in initialization:

```js
 const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: "*" } });
```